# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, promise, setstate

I have this error:

```
bundle.js:2066 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable.
```

My code:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user)
  {
    if (user.uid != null)
    {
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("Users/" + user.uid);
      console.log(storageRef)
      storageRef.listAll().then( res => {
        let promises = res.items.forEach( item => item.getDownloadURL() );
    
        Promise.all(promises).then((downloadURLs) => {
            this.setState({ urlImage: downloadURLs });
        })
      })
    }

    console.log(this.state.urlImage)

    const actionPhoto = { type: "TOGGLE_PHOTO", value: this.state.urlImage };
    this.props.dispatch(actionPhoto)

    const actionUid = { type: "TOGGLE_UID", value: user.uid };
    this.props.dispatch(actionUid)

    // On ajoute le nom et la photo du current user
    const actionName = { type: "TOGGLE_NAME", value: user.displayName };
    this.props.dispatch(actionName)

    //this.props.navigation.navigate('Navigation')
}
})
```

I have one item in `foreach(items)` and `ref()` storage firebase is good.

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, make sure your res object has `items` and it must be an array.
Then, change your forEach iterator to `map`, so it generates a new mapped array based on your res.items.

```
let promises = res.items.map( item => item.getDownloadURL() );

Promise.all(promises).then((downloadURLs) => {
            this.setState({ urlImage: downloadURLs });
        })
```

Comment: Ok, Map worked ! thanks you
And in promises, i forgot [ ] = Promise.all([promises])

Last question : Now, i have an array :
[D]
0: D
a: 2
b: null
c: null
f: null
g: false
h: false
i: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

How i get only the path ?

Comment: You should use resolved items as a return value not the promise itself. Defining [] = Promise.all and using that [] array only returns the promise object itself. You should do whatever you want to do on the resolution array, in your case it is downloadURLs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the line `let promises = res.items.forEach( item => item.getDownloadURL());`

The `forEach()` function [returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Use the `map()` function instead which [returns the resulting array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

`let promises = res.items.map( item => item.getDownloadURL() );`