# firestore react "TypeError: is not iterable" when append to array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The data is the database is:

```
Comment:
{
     uid1:"a"
     uid2:"b"
}
```

and I wanted to add `CommentContent` which is:

```
uid3:"c"
```

I am trying to read from the database, append data to the data then update the database, and below is my code:

```
  const OriginalContentSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "Comment", curSnap.id));
  const OriginalContent = OriginalContentSnap.data();
  const CommentContent = {[uid] : commentDocID.id};
  CommentContent = [...OriginalContent, CommentContent];
```

however, everything is fine until the last line where I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: OriginalContent is not iterable
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the document format you are retrieving from the database? Please edit the question with document format. Otherwise it would be hard to answer this question.

Comment: console.log `OriginalContent` to see what it is. Seems like its not an array, so you get that error

Comment: user1998844, please let me know if the answer below was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The“OriginalContentSnapdata ()”,returns an object, which you can't iterate over ,please check this helpful [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) document regarding the details of the Snapshot data variables and data types,on the returned object.
You should make sure your resulting object has items and it must be an array. Then, change your iterator, so it generates an array based on your fetch results.

Check the below for similar examples which will be helpful:

- [Uncaught Typeerror Object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090914/uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-iterable-cannot-read-property-symbolsymbol-i)
- [Type error undefined is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003971/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-undefined-is-not-iterable)
- [Object is not iterable cannot read property symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583891/uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-iterable-cannot-read-property-symbolsymbol-i)
- [Object null is not iterable cannot read property symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323412/uncaught-typeerror-object-null-is-not-iterable-cannot-read-property-symbolsym)